# I want to generate image objects in random locations in psychopy

Tags: psychopy

Is there are way to generate image objects to appear in random locations, with the constraint that one has to be a target that appears in one of the 12 possible distractor locations?

Comment: I imagine so. But you will really have to give a much more precise description of what you want to implement. There are very many ways to interpret what you wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's right, more info would be useful but if I've understood you right then try something like this:

1/ add a custom code object to your trial loop

2/ in the 'Begin Experiment' tab:

```
import random, copy
from random import randint
from decimal import *

# setup an array to store 6 locations to randomly allocate to our shapes 
# (or select random locations between (-1,-1) and (1,1) if you want them completely 
# random though you then need to factor in overlaying shapes)
master_positions=[[0.2,0.6],[0.2,0],[0.2,-0.6],[0.6,0.6],[0.6,0],[0.6,-0.6]]
positions = copy.deepcopy(master_positions)
```

3/ in the 'Begin routine' tab:

```
# reset 'positions' 
positions = copy.deepcopy(master_positions) 

#randomise this for each trial
random.shuffle(positions)
```

4/ Then, on the image/polygon (or whatever) for your object, instead of hard-coding the (x,y) coordinates, reference the positions variable instead.  Remember to change the drop-down menu option on the right of it from 'constant' to 'set every repeat'
e.g.

```
$positions[3]
```

So if you have 6 objects to randomly position, then use `$positions[0] .. [5]`  , one for each object

You could do something similar to change the size, colour, .. too.

Hopefully that gives you the gist. regarding the distractor locations, you could have 2 arrays to store locations instead of one and randomly pick one from the distractor list to use each time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you have 12 stimuli that you want placed in random locations, with the constraint that one of the images (chosen at random) needs to occur at one location (randomly selected) in a set of fixed locations.

i think the correct approach is to generate your stimuli locations first, then assign each location to an image afterwards:

```
import numpy as np

# define fixed locations
fixedlocations=np.array([[100,10],
                         [-50,20],
                         [10,50]])

# define window constants
winx = 500
winy = 400

# get list of random locations
locations =  np.random.uniform(low = -1,high = 1, size = [12,2])

# scale locations to window size
locations[:,0] *= winx
locations[:,1] *= winy

# i think psychopy requires integers for coordinates
locations =  locations.round()

# pick a random fixed location and insert into the random locations
whichrandom = np.random.randint(low=0, high=12)
whichfixed = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2)

# substitute a random fixed location in at a random row
locations[whichrandom,:] = fixedlocations[whichfixed,:]
```

All i've done there is randomly generate a set of 12 possible locations in window, and then substituted one (randomly selected) location with a randomly selected location from a fixed set.

Then, you can assign locations to each stimulus using a for loop. if your stimuli are in a list, you can do something like this:

```
for i in range(12):
    mystimuli[i].setPos(locations[i,:])
```